# TypeError when creating SubClass

Tags: python, class

I have a parents class defined as:

```
class Alpha(X, Y, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, time_series : pandas.Series):
        super(Alpha, self).__init__()
```

And I have its Child Class:

```
class Beta(Alpha):
    def __init__(self, returns: [daily_returns_object]):
        super(Beta, self).__init__()
        self.calibrate(returns)
```

I try to create a `Beta` Object according to:

```
#returns_list has been defined but is irrelevant here
beta_obj = Beta(returns_list)
```

I get the error `TypeError:__init__() missing one positional argument: 'time_series'`. Hence, I wrote `beta_obj = Beta(time_series, returns_list)` but then get the error `TypeError:__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Comment: Your `Beta` accepts only `returns` but your `Alpha` accept sonly `time_series`.  What do you actually want to pass?  If you only pass `returns` to Beta, how is it supposed to know what to pass as `time_series` to `Alpha`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `Alpha.__init__` method here:

```
super(Beta, self).__init__()
```

but you are not passing in the required `time_series` argument there.

If that's an argument that `Beta` takes too, you'll need to add it to your `Beta.__init__` definition, then pass it on:

```
class Beta(Alpha):
    def __init__(self, time_series: pandas.Series, returns: [daily_returns_object]):
        super(Beta, self).__init__(time_series)
        self.calibrate(returns)
```

Comment: Thanks. So, `time_series : pandas.Series`needs to be passed to `Beta`s `__init__()` then or is it not necessary?

Comment: @FixIncome: `Beta.__init__` replaces `Alpha.__init__`. By using `super()`__init__()` you call it anyway, so you need to satisfy the required parameters for that method when you call it. The best way to do so is for `Beta` to accept an extra argument you then pass on.